# Analytical solution of constrained linear least-squares problems with bounds x ≤ ub

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, least-squares, quadratic-programming

Considering the following constrained linear least-squares problem:
[constrained linear least-squares problems with bounds  x ≤ 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZRYv.png)

min (1/2) *||(C.x-d)||^2 , x<=0

where d is scalar( 1*1); C and x are vectors (e.g. C can be 1*m and x can be m*1). Is there any analytical solution for that? Can we find the optimum point (x) without using any optimization toolbox?

Comment: I assume $C$ is a matrix and $d$ is a vector.  What is "ub"?  Can we just write that as $x \leq v$ for some vector $v$? There does not seem to be any need to multiply $u$ times some other thing $b$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks Michael. d is scalar( 1*1), C and x are vectors.  x<=0.

Comment: @Wok Did you find any analytical solution for a Linear Least Squares with Non Negativity Constraint?

Comment: If $c$ is orthogonal to a vector $r=(r_1,...,r_m)$ such that $r_i<0$ for all $i$, then we can find any solution $x^*$ to the _unconstrained_ problem of minimizing $(cx-d)^2$, then write $y^*=x^* + \theta r$ for sufficiently large $\theta>0$ to ensure all components of $y^*$ are nonnegative.  And $y^*$ is optimal for the constrained problem, with an optimal value equal to that of the unconstrained problem. If $c$ is _not_ orthogonal to such a vector $r$, then $c$ must have all its components nonpositive.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $C$ is a matrix, there's no closed form solution for this problem.  With a simple change of variable you can get constraints $x \geq 0$, and then you can use one of many algorithms for the non-negative least squares (NNLS) problem.

If $C$ is simply a row vector (odd notation), then see @Michael's answer.

Comment: @Brian.Borchers Is there a proof/intuition for that?

Answer (score 1):

You want to find $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to minimize $|c^Tx-d|$ subject to $x \leq 0$, where $c$ is a given vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $d$ a given real number. This is not difficult.  An optimal solution $x^*=(x_1^*, ..., x_n^*)$ can be found that has at most one nonzero component.

#### Case 1: Suppose $d\geq 0$:

-If there is an $i \in\{1, ... ,n\}$ such that $c_i<0$, then define $x_i^*=\frac{d}{c_i}$ and $x_j^*=0$ for all $j \neq i$. Then $|c^Tx^*-d|=0$ and $x^*\leq 0$.

-Else, $c_i \geq 0$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.  Thus, $c^Tx \leq 0$ for any vector $x$ that satisfies $x \leq 0$.  It follows that $x^*=0$ is optimal.

#### Case 2: Suppose $d<0$:

-If there is an $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ such that $c_i>0$, then define $x_i^*=\frac{d}{c_i}$ and $x_j^*=0$ for all $j \neq i$.  Then $|c^Tx^*-d|=0$ and $x^*\leq 0$.

-Else, $c_i \leq 0$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.  Thus, $c^Tx \geq 0$ for any vector $x$ that satisfies $x \leq 0$.  It follows that $x^*=0$ is optimal.